# jquery .val() is not working

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".container").val(" ");
</script>
```

I have been trying to set the value inside a div having a class container, but it doesn't seem to be working here, what should i do to make it work?

Comment: Link to the documenation, http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `text()` or `html()` for `div/span`, `val()` is used for `input`

```
$(".container").text(" ");
```

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Yes this seems right, Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use .html() if it is a div

```
$(".container").html(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is for text inputs, it maps to the `value` attribute.

Additionally, you don't need to use the `type` attribute on `<script>` elements...

Answer (score 0):

The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns null.

[Check the .val() specifications](http://api.jquery.com/val/)